# Quando usare "da + infinito" invece di "per + infinito"

Tags: verbs, prepositions, infinitive

In quale situazione si dovrebbe usare *da + infinito* invece di *per + infinito*? Per esempio:

- *questo regola è difficile **da** capire* (da **non** per)
- *quindi ho chiesto questo domanda **per** capire la differenza.* (per, **non** da)

A quanto mi risulta, *per + infinito* è usato in situazioni simili a quelle in cui si userebbe un gerundio in inglese, però non sono sicuro che sia una regola ferrea.

---

Edit

Credo di aver capito che:

- "da" è usato nelle situazioni in cui si intende "si deve fare qualcosa" o "che possa essere fatto"
- "per" è simile alle espressioni "in modo di", "allo scopo di" o "da usare per"

Penso che sia utile mostrare la differenze tra "da" e "per" usandoli in modo da cambiare il significato della frase.

- Ho un appartamento da affittare. *(Possiedo un appartamento che posso affittarti)*
- Ho un appartamento per affittare†. *(Possiedo un appartamento al solo fine di affittarlo)*

---

- Ho un libro per scrivere. *(Possiedo un libro su cui posso scrivere)*
- Ho un libro da scrivere *(Devo scrivere un intero libro)*

Mi sbaglio in questa supposizione?

† *Questa frase è grammaticalmente scorretta e non è il modo in cui dovrebbe essere formulata, però è solo a titolo descrittivo.*

Comment: Attenzione: si dice “infinito”, non “infinitivo”!

Comment: Grazie però io sento sia _infinitivo_ sia _infinito_ tutti i giorni.

Comment: In italiano esiste la parola “infinitivo”, ma per indicare il modo verbale infinito è desueta; ora si usa solo come aggettivo per certi concetti grammaticali, come le proposizioni infinitive. Vedi qui: https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/infinitivo/?search=infinitivo

Comment: Sai cosa voglio dire e non penso che c'è molta ambiguità quando usando _infinitivo_ invece di _infinito_. La domanda non è "quale parola dovrei usare _infinitivo_ od _infinito_" oppure è sul modo di usare "da" o "per" prima un _**infinitivo**_. Le tue opinioni, al di fuori una risposta alla mia domanda, non mi interessano.

Comment: @fdcpp Esistono grammatiche italiane che usano “infinitivo” per il modo verbale? Non mi risulta.

Comment: @fdcpp: A te possono non interessare,  ma questo sito è dedicato a chi è interessato alla lingua italiana, e per questo è bene che i testi delle domande siano in italiano corretto, indipendentemente dalle tue preferenze personali.

Comment: Inoltre una forma scorretta rende più difficile trovare un argomento a chi lo cerca.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grosso modo, direi che si usa "da" quando l'oggetto riceve l'azione, e "per" quando l'oggetto esegue l'azione o è usato per eseguirla. La differenza è sottile e, a volte, i due termini possono essere anche essere scambiati producendo frasi strane ma comprensibili.

Per esempio:

- Ho una mela da mangiare

La mela non mangia - viene mangiata. Però "Ho una mela per mangiare" non è completamente sbagliato, perché la mela mi consente di mangiare.

- Ho una matita per scrivere

La matita scrive, non "viene scritta" (serve *per* scrivere). Quindi uso "per".

- Questa regola è difficile da capire

Una regola non "capisce", viene capita.

- Ho un appartamento da affittare

L'appartamento non "affitta", viene affittato; quindi uso "da". Detto per inciso, trovo brutta la frase "Ho un appartamento per affittarlo". Questa costruzione sarebbe più adatta in un contesto dove si accenni a un chiodo, e allora potrei dire "Ho un martello per piantarlo" (il chiodo).

- C'è una porta per passare / da passare

"...per passare" indica che la porta è messa lì a permettere il passaggio. "...da passare" indica che la porta *deve* essere passata (per arrivare a una data meta). Nel primo caso, "per", la porta è come un utensile che permette di eseguire un'azione; nel secondo caso ("da") la porta rappresenta il complemento oggetto e "viene passata".

Comment: Le tue distinzioni sono giuste, ma non così assolute, la preposizione *da* può indicare anche scopo, destinazione etc. alla pari di *per*, veramente difficile vedere una regola, credo che conti piuttosto l'uso. Dal dizionario Treccani, voce *da*: attitudine, capacità, uso, scopo, destinazione: cavallo da corsa, cappello da prete, abito da passeggio, veste da camera, vino da pasto  (sono considerati usi meno proprî, ma ormai comunissimi, festa da ballo, messa da requiem, biglietto da visita, per festa di ballo, ecc.; e così macchina da scrivere, da cucire, al posto di macchina per scrivere etc.

Comment: Hai ragione @BakerStreet, infatti ho iniziato la risposta con un bel "Grosso modo". Però, la connotazione di attitudine ecc. del Treccani cita esempi con sostantivi, non con l'infinito (cavallo da corsa ecc.). E le macchine dovrebbero essere "per" scrivere, "per cucire", anche se quasi universalmente si usa il "da" (che a me non piace, come non piace etc. al posto di ecc. :-) ).

Comment: Sì sì, non era una critica alla tua risposta (a cui ho dato +1) ma una precisazione per l'OP sull'uso di *da*.

Comment: @BakerStreet nessun problema... la mia era una precisazione sulla precisazione :-)

Answer (score -1):

Non ti sbagli. Devi solo stare attento al fatto che nella frase  'Ho un appartamento per affittare' , 'affittare' è sbagliato perchè il complemento oggetto è l'appartamento, quindi la frase corretta è "ho un appartamento per affittarlo".

Comment: Risposta un po' vaga... che ne dici di "Ho un paio di forbici per tagliare"?

Comment: In che senso? Non è giusto quello che hai scritto?

Comment: Nel tuo commento hai scritto "hai"? Certo che è giusto quello che ho scritto, ma nella tua risposta dici che sarebbe sbagliato e dovrei dire "Ho un paio di forbici per tagliarle". Mi sembra. E indubbiamente, col verbo tagliare, le forbici agiscono da soggetto.

Comment: Hai ragione scusa, è perché l'appartamento è il complemento oggetto... correggo subito!

Comment: Scusa... non sarei così sicuro che si tratti di soggetto o complemento oggetto. Nella frase "Dispongo di un appartamente da affittare" l'appartamento non è strettamente complemento oggetto, eppure...

Comment: Scusa, ma non capisco il problema... perché eppure?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151941/discussion-between-qualcuno2-and-linuxfan-says-reinstate-monica).